# The complex conjugate transpose of an array in c++

Tags: c++, matlab, c++14, transpose, complex-numbers

I am trying to write a code in c++ equivalents to the following Matlab code:

```matlab
n = 32;
s1 = dlmread('ssa.txt');
s2 = dlmread('ssb.txt');
fd1 = fft(s1);
fd2 = fft(s2);
nf = sqrt((fd1 * fd1') * (fd2 * fd2')) / n
```

Where

```
ssa.txt=  0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

and

```
ssb.txt=  0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1
```

Unfortunately the result I am getting in c++ is bit different from Matlab

result from Matlab:

```
nf = 12
```

result in c++:

```
nf(4.88621,0)
```

My c++ code :

```
//iterDelayEst.cpp
#include <complex>
#include "binFreq.cpp"
#include <valarray>

typedef std::complex<double> Complex;
typedef std::valarray<Complex> CArray;

double iterDelayEst(int n, CArray& x, CArray& y)
{
/**********************************************constants************************************************
*******************************************************************************************************/
    //exit if uncertainty below threshold
    fft(x);
    fft(y);
    auto fd2Tau = y;
    //frequency domain representation of signals
    std::vector<double> tau;

    auto f = binFreq(n);

    std::vector<double> e;
    Complex nf3(0.0,0.0);

    int j;
    for ( j = 0 ; j < n ; j++ )
    {
        auto op = [](CArray::value_type v) {
            return std::conj(v);
        };
        auto nf1 = ((x * x.apply(op)) * (y * y.apply(op)));
        nf3 += nf1[j];
    }
    auto nf2 =std::sqrt(nf3);
    auto nf =nf2/(double)n;
    cout << "nf" << nf <<endl;
}
```

my main.cpp:

```
#include <complex>
#include <iostream>
#include <valarray>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include "fft.cpp"
#include "cs_delay.cpp"
#include "iterDelayEst.cpp"
using namespace std;
char filename[]  = "myfile.txt";
char filename2[] = "myfile2.txt";

typedef std::complex<double> Complex;
typedef std::valarray <Complex> CArray;
/***********************************************************************************************
*                                 function declarations
************************** ******************************************************** ***********/
void fft(CArray& x);
void ifft(CArray& x);
std::vector<double> binFreq(int n);
void cs_delay(CArray& x, int rate_hz, int delay_s, int n);
double iterDelayEst(int n, CArray& x, CArray& x2);

int main()
{
    int dTest_samples;
    int cTest;
    int n=299;
    int i;
    int j;
    double x [n];
    double y [n];
    int rate_hz=1;
    int delay_s=30;

    /*****************************getting x*******************************/

    string line;
    double Result;
    ifstream myfile (filename);
    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
        for ( i = 0 ; (i < n) && (myfile >> x[i]) ; ++i)
            cout << line << '\n';
        stringstream convert(line);

        if ( !(convert >> Result) )
            Result = 0;
        x[i]=Result;
    }
    else cout << "Unable to open file";
    /*****************************getting y******************************/
    string line2;
    double Result2;
    ifstream myfile2 (filename2);
    if (myfile2.is_open())
    {
        for ( i = 0 ; (i < n) && (myfile2 >> y[i]) ; ++i)
            cout << line2 << '\n';
        stringstream convert(line2);

        if ( !(convert >> Result2) )
            Result2 = 0;
        y[i]=Result2;
    }
    else cout << "Unable to open file2";
    /***********************************************************************/
    /*********************for x******************/
    Complex test[n];

    for ( i = 0 ; i < n ; ++i )
        test[i] = x[i];

    CArray data(test,n);
    /*********************for y******************/
    Complex test2[n];

    for ( j = 0 ; j < n ; ++j )
        test2[j] = y[j];

    CArray data2(test2,n);

    // forward fft
    fft(data);

    std::cout << "fft" << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i <n; ++i)
    {
        cout << data[i] << endl;
    }

    // inverse fft
    ifft(data);

    std::cout << std::endl << "ifft" << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i <n; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << data[i] << std::endl;
    }

    cs_delay(data, 1, 6, n);
    for (int i = 0; i <n; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << data[i] << std::endl;
    }

    iterDelayEst(n, data, data2 );

    return 0;
}
```

the fft function:

```
//fft.cpp
using namespace std;
const double PI = 3.141592653589793238460;

/************************************************************************************************
*                      Cooley–Tukey FFT (in-place, divide-and-conquer)                          *
*              Higher memory requirements and redundancy although more intuitive                *
************************************************************************************************/

typedef std::complex<double> Complex;
typedef std::valarray<Complex> CArray;
// Cooley–Tukey FFT (in-place, divide-and-conquer)
// Higher memory requirements and redundancy although more intuitive
void fft(CArray& x)
{
    const size_t N = x.size();
    if (N <= 1) return;

    // divide
    CArray even = x[std::slice(0, N/2, 2)];
    CArray  odd = x[std::slice(1, N/2, 2)];

    // conquer
    fft(even);
    fft(odd);

    // combine
    for (size_t k = 0; k < N/2; ++k)
    {
        Complex t = std::polar(1.0, -2 * PI * k / N) * odd[k];
        x[k    ] = even[k] + t;
        x[k+N/2] = even[k] - t;
    }
}
```

result of my fft in matlab:

```
>> fft([0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]')

9.0000 + 0.0000i
  -3.3099 - 1.8957i
   0.0000 - 5.0273i
  -3.7722 + 5.1864i
   1.0000 + 0.0000i
   2.4654 + 1.0512i
  -0.0000 - 1.4966i
  -0.9547 - 0.4595i
   1.0000 + 0.0000i
  -1.3771 + 0.0371i
   0.0000 - 0.6682i
  -0.4381 + 1.8523i
   1.0000 + 0.0000i
   0.5733 - 0.8409i
   0.0000 - 0.1989i
  -1.1867 - 0.2275i
   1.0000 + 0.0000i
  -1.1867 + 0.2275i
   0.0000 + 0.1989i
   0.5733 + 0.8409i
   1.0000 + 0.0000i
  -0.4381 - 1.8523i
   0.0000 + 0.6682i
  -1.3771 - 0.0371i
   1.0000 + 0.0000i
  -0.9547 + 0.4595i
  -0.0000 + 1.4966i
   2.4654 - 1.0512i
   1.0000 + 0.0000i
  -3.7722 - 5.1864i
   0.0000 + 5.0273i
  -3.3099 + 1.8957i
```

result of my fft in c++:

```
(9,0)
(-3.3099,-1.89568)
(1.72253e-16,-5.02734)
(-3.77219,5.1864)
(1,0)
(2.46544,1.05123)
(2.94822e-16,-1.49661)
(-0.954746,-0.459467)
(1,0)
(-1.37707,0.0371386)
(-6.28295e-17,-0.668179)
(-0.438105,1.85232)
(1,0)
(0.573279,-0.840935)
(2.78992e-16,-0.198912)
(-1.18671,-0.227505)
(1,0)
(-1.18671,0.227505)
(1.72253e-16,0.198912)
(0.573279,0.840935)
(1,0)
(-0.438105,-1.85232)
(-3.82452e-17,0.668179)
(-1.37707,-0.0371386)
(1,0)
(-0.954746,0.459467)
(-3.67545e-17,1.49661)
(2.46544,-1.05123)
(1,0)
(-3.77219,-5.1864)
(-7.8049e-16,5.02734)
(-3.3099,1.89568)
```

Let assume the result of nf is correct, I added new lines 
new added lines :

```
for ( j = 0 ; j < n ; j++ ){
    auto xcorr2=(fd2Tau * x.apply(std::conj));
    auto xcorr3=(std::abs(xcorr2[i]))/nf;
    cout << "xcorr3" << xcorr3[i] << endl;
}
```

unfortunately now I am receiving following errors messages:

```
In file included from myfft.cpp:16:0:
iterDelayEst.cpp: In function ‘double iterDelayEst(int, CArray&, CArray&)’:
iterDelayEst.cpp:61:30: error: no match for ‘operator[]’ (operand types are ‘std::complex<double>’ and ‘int’)
    cout << "xcorr3" << xcorr3[i] << endl;


                              ^
```

Can someone help me to sort out what I am doing wrong?

I correct the code and I am not getting the error any more. However, I added new lines, I would like to transform this Matlab code  ( ix = find(xcorr == max(xcorr)); ) to c++ 
The code find  indices of values corresponding to the maximum of xcorr elements. I have written following code for the purpose :

```
find.cpp:
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdio>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
int main() {
    std::vector<double> v;
    v.push_back(1);
    v.push_back(3);
    v.push_back(5);
    v.push_back(0);
    v.push_back(7);
    v.push_back(1);
    v.push_back(7);

    std::vector<double>::iterator result ;
    const double maxim = *max_element(v.begin(), v.end());
    for(result = std::find(v.begin(), v.end(), maxim); result != v.end(); result = std::find(result + 1, v.end(), maxim))
    {
           cout << "maximum found at index " << result -v.begin() +1 << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I need to incorporate this code into my iterDelayEst.cpp function, I don't see how I can send the result (array) from xcorr as argument to find function so that it use as vector

Comment: This isn't even close to minimal.

Comment: How does the ifft relate to the Matlab code? Also what function is the first place where things go wrong?

Comment: Hi Patrick, The ifft is not used so far ,  I will use it later in my program. so only consider fft.  I edited the code, now it is without ifft. Things go wrong from line  :auto nf1 = ((x * x.apply(op)) * (y * y.apply(op)));

Comment: Ok so does this mean that the FFT returns the correct result? And more correctly, has everything been tested to be ok until the line `auto nf1 = ((x * x.apply(op)) * (y * y.apply(op)));`?

Comment: YES, the result of my fft function is almost the same in Matlab and C++, however C++ seems to be more precise. Matlab round down 1.72253e-16 to 0.  I made all tests before that line.

Comment: Ok I see, so my suggestion is that you run the function on an easy example array and test the output per command. Spontaneously it looks as if the loop is out of place since you use the binary `*` operator on two arrays. This gives the impression that you do not have full control on what you are doing. Try to run the code line by line and check output.

Comment: Patrick, let assume the result returned by my function is  correct, I added new lines in code , and now I am receiving some error message see above.

Comment: Well it seems as subscript operator `[]` is not defined for your class http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators. And I still think you need to go through the function step-by-step and debug. The reason you have these problems is that you perform multiple operations on on line and thus cannot debug each operation.

Comment: The correct code should be :                                    std::vector<double> v;
x = x.apply(std::conj);
y *= x;
ifft(y);
y =std::abs(y);
y=y/nf;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct code :

```
double iterDelayEst(int n, CArray& x, CArray& y)
{

    //exit if uncertainty below threshold
    fft(x);
    fft(y);
    auto fd2Tau = y;
    //frequency domain representation of signals
    std::vector<double> tau;

    auto f = binFreq(n);

    std::vector<double> e;
    Complex nf3(0.0,0.0);

    int j;
    for ( j = 0 ; j < n ; j++ )
    {
        auto nfa=(x * x.apply(std::conj));
        nf4 +=nfa[j];

        auto nfb=(y * y.apply(std::conj));
        nf5 +=nfb[j];

    }

    auto nf1 = (nf4 * nf5);
    auto nf2 =std::sqrt(nf1);
    auto nf =nf2/(double)n;
    cout << "nf1" << nf1 <<endl;
    cout << "nf2" << nf2 <<endl;
    cout << "nf" << nf <<endl;
}
```